# update vectors of children's geometry of transformed object in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

i have a container object with several circles and a box.
I try to link circles with box vertices.

schematic code

```
initLayout();
var box = addBox(); // a mesh
var circles = createCircles(); // circles has an Object3D type
scene.add(circles);
createLines(box.geometry.vertices, circles.children); // create line for each pair of vertices and add it to scene

render();
function update(){
    // the function invoked each animation frame
    //  and here i should update vectors
}
```

here a full example: https://jsfiddle.net/basilkot/b732euf4/6/

container and box rotates but vectors have the same coordinates, because i rotate a mesh but not vectors.

is threre a way to apply transform matrix to each children vector?

Comment: Is this what you aree trying to do? https://jsfiddle.net/b732euf4/7/ ?

Comment: almost. red circles should be rotated in front always (about z axis only), but box should be rotated about two axes. lines should link circles and vertices of box